# Multiple select with one more value associated with it in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm planning to add multiple select field into my project but the problem is I want to capture one more integer value along with every selected value,Can anyone suggest me best way of selecting the value along with multiple select. My multiple select dropdown look like this.. and thanks in advance

```
<div class=" multiselectdd "><multiselect ng-model="vm.inventory.SiteId" options="site.value as site.label for site in vm.sites"  data-header-key="header"data-divider-key="divider" scroll-after-rows="5"filter-after-rows="0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it properly but if you want to select more than one object in your select list you can:

> Javascript Side

```
$scope.SelectedChanged = function (yourModel) {
  if (yourModel.length > 1) {
    $scope.newModel = yourModel[1];
  }
};
```

> HTML Side

```
<select name="yourElementName" multiple ng-model="yourModel" ng-change="SelectedChanged(yourModel)">
  <option value="0">One</option>
  <option value="1">Two</option>
  <option value="2">Tree</option>
  <option value="3">Four</option>
</select>
```

and call your model to test

```
<span>{{yourModel}} - Second Value: {{newModel}} </span>
```

When you select multiple element lets say " One and Two " you will see like:

> Output

["0","1"] - Second Value: 1

Comment: I want to capture the second value through the input box

Comment: Then  you can just put ng-change="" directive in your Select element and create add second value to new object please see the changes above